# generate controller empty app view folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller

This is just occurring with me or this new rails when i generate a new controller the view folder still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views aren't created until you generate them through one of the `rails generate` commands, or manually by adding in files.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: that's the point i did the command already, but the folder still empty. otherwise the scaffold create the files properly

Comment: When you generate a controller, you can include any number of actions in the command.  For each action, rails will generate a view.  No actions => no views.  `scaffold` generates a RESTful controller, so index/create/new/edit/destroy/update/show actions, and corresponding views, are created automatically when you use `rails generate scaffold`.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a method to the generate command

```
Rails generate controller yourcontroller index
```

I found this will make the controller and the view